# Loading a raster using Openlayers and Mapserver

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, web-mapping, javascript, mapserver

I'm trying to load a raster into my browser using [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/). I can examine my WMS raster layer using [OpenJump](http://www.openjump.org/), but I'm not able to get it to load into my browser. My mapfile is as follows:

```
MAP      
    ###########
    NAME         "ny_pop"
    SHAPEPATH     "/v0.3/mapserver/"                                                                              
    UNITS         meters
    EXTENT        -8269337 4955373 -8190365 5005745 
    SIZE          1000 1000
    STATUS        ON
    DEBUG         ON
    IMAGETYPE     "png"

    ###########    
    PROJECTION
        "init=epsg:900913"
    END

    ###########
OUTPUTFORMAT
  NAME "png"
  DRIVER AGG/PNG
  MIMETYPE "image/png"
  IMAGEMODE RGB
  EXTENSION "png"
  FORMATOPTION "GAMMA=0.75"
END

    ###########    
    WEB             
        METADATA
            "wms_title"           "WMS Pop Tif"
            "wms_onlineresource"  "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=raster_1.map&"            
            "wms_enable_request"  "GetMap GetFeatureInfo GetCapabilities"
        END
    END

    ###########
    LAYER
        NAME      "ny_pop"
        DATA      /home/mysite/webapps/htdocs/v0.3/mapserver/ny_pop.tif
        STATUS    ON
        TYPE      RASTER   
        METADATA
            "wms_title"  "WMS NY Raster"
            "wms_srs"    "EPSG:900913"
        END
    END

    ########### 
END
```

Everything (map, raster and mapfile) are using EPSG:900913, and I have an existing map (centered around New York) which I am adding the layer `rasterLayer` to. My javascript is as follows:

```
function generateRaster(){

    console.log('get map bounds');
    bounds = map.getExtent();

    rasterLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
           "ny_pop",
           "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?", 
           {map: 'raster_1.map'},
           {'maxExtent': bounds}
       );
    console.log(rasterLayer);
    map.addLayer(rasterLayer);

}
```

I'm trying to limit the raster to the bounds of the map using the `{'maxExtent': bounds}` command, but I also tried with just the map name and URL and it did not work either. I'm still trying to get my head around the `.map` format, so there could be some mistakes there also. However, as I could view the raster in OpenJump I assumed it was ok.

**EDIT:**
I updated my javascript to the following:

```
rasterLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
   "NY Population layer..... ",
   "http://urbmet.webfactional.com/mapserv.cgi?", 
   {map: 'raster_1.map', layers: 'ny_pop'}
);
```

but still nothing shows up on the map. I've added a screencapture of my firebug output - this is the contents of `console.log(rasterLayer)`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the layers parameter in the WMS constructor in OpenLayers:

```
rasterLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( 
       "This Can Be Any Name",
       "http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?", 
       {map: 'raster_1.map', layers: 'ny_pop'},
       {'maxExtent': bounds}
   );
```

http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Layer/WMS

You also may have to add in the EPSG:900913 definition to your `proj\nad\epsg` definitions in your MapServer installation.

I'm assuming your TIF file is georeferenced, and falls within the extents you set in your MAP file: `-8269337 4955373 -8190365 5005745`

I usually set the SIZE parameter to match the default OpenLayers tiles:

```
SIZE 256 256
```

I also set the STATUS to OFF for both Map and Layer - calling the WMS will then only bring back the layers you specify.

You can also set up an error log to see if any errors are recorded by MapServer:

```
CONFIG "MS_ERRORFILE" "tmp/ms.log"
```

Finally what are you getting back - empty images, or error messages?

Comment: Thanks @geographika. I added the `layers:'ny_pop'` and checked that `EPSG:900913` is in `proj\nad\epsg` (it is), but still no luck. Could there be anything else that I am doing wrong? It seems that the osgeo examples do not typically have a `map:'...'` component.

Comment: I just updated my question a little.  I added the error logging, and updated the tile size to 256, but no errors are produced when I run the javascript. How can I tell if my tif is georeferenced? I exported it from ArcGIS and copied it to my server so I assumed it was. Nothing is happening in the browser, no error messages or empty images.

Comment: You can take off the  {'maxExtent': bounds} parameter - OpenLayers will call the WMS when it is visible in the map bounds.

Comment: Is it possible that it is sending the WMS request using `epsg:4362`? As I looked through the firebug output I saw the line `yx Object { EPSG:4326=true}`

Comment: @celenius - install Fiddler or look at the net tab in Firebug to see the exact requests sent from the browser

Comment: I did get this to work: `OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("NY_Pop_Layer",     "http://urbmet.webfactional.com/mapserv.cgi?map=raster_1.map&",  {layers: 'ny_pop_den'});` I think `map` was not being added on properly to the url.